# How to execute multiple different Sql Server stored procedures with jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I need to execute different Sql Server stored procedures. My sql string is as below: 
"{call sp1(?)};{call sp2(?)};"
but it returns 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Does someone know how to handle this case?

I have tried 
"{call sp1(?)};{call sp2(?)};"
"{call sp1(?)}{call sp2(?)}"

both don't work.

Here is a sample code I've tried:

String ps = "{call sp1(?)};{call sp2(?)};";

jdbcTemplate.update(ps);

Comment: Why can't you execute update twice?

Comment: I have many SPs to call, I want to batch them together to improve performance.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch12s04.html

Comment: This is the way that it calls the same stored procedures, but thank you for your help!